# Read image from varbinary case sql server c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, image

I have a problem when I try to convert stream to image. It shows me an error in:
`Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);`

```
if (reader[12] != System.DBNull.Value)
{
    Byte[] image = (Byte[])reader[12];
    c.image = byteArrayToImage(image);
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ms.Close();
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: what kind of error did you get ?

Comment: As an aside, you can do `new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)` and save yuorself the `Write` and `Seek` calls.

Comment: Yeah. It shows you an error. Are we supposed to guess or put work in, or can you - ah - be smart enough to actually tell us the error, too? Hint: One look at the code, the error and you may realize READING the error sort of makes sense.

Comment: a first it showed me that it can't read a closed stream, i delete ms.close() now it shows me Le paramètre n'est pas valide. (invalid parameter)

Comment: @user3710293 See the answers Dmitry and I gave and pick the one you like better. The "Invalid Pararmeter" error is thrown because you pass a closed stream to the `FromStream` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not *close* the stream *so soon*:

```
   ms.Close();  // <- That's wrong:
   // You can't create an image from a disposed stream
   Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Do it like that:

```
  ...
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    ms.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return Image.FromStream(ms);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ms.Close();  // <-- Remove this line

Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
return returnImage;
```

In this code you close the stream before creating the image. You can not read from a closed stream. Change your code to this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
{
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

That code *may*  generate GDI+ errors. So you don't have to be afraid of not disposing of the stream at all. The garbage collector will do this anyway, so if you get errors in GDI+, use this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
return returnImage;
```